# One would a pack of leprous dogs clinging to life

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am reading the book NIGHT written by Elie Wiesel. Here is a sentence I don't understand: He looked at us as one would a pack of leprous dogs clinging to life.

Does the "would" here is equivalent to "have" like "have sb doing sth"?

[image]

Comment: Among the results of this search are more examples of the dropping of a word:  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20you%20would%20a%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means:

> He looked at us as one would look at a pack of leprous dogs.

The verb **look** was omitted in the second part of the sentence.